# Loading Scripts with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have set up a page so that it loads content in with AJAX by selector. This is how the code looks, for anyone who isn't familiar

```
$('#container').load(content.php + .classname)
```

Super straightforward. Each div I load, I also have a little block of script in the bottom, holding variables for the identification of that block, which I am keeping track of separately. For example:

```
<div class="classname"> 
    <p>Here's my content!</p> 
    <script> var contentID = 4; </script> 
</div>
```

The problem I have run into is that when I load in the content, while all the content comes in totally fine, it's not loading in the script, it just cuts that entire section right out.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening, or how to solve this problem? I am aware of the getScript() function, but I need to load in both html and script at the same time. In addition, i have a bunch of different things to load, with just about one line of unique script for each one, so it would be a total waste to make an external JS file for each one...

Comment: I'm confused, does the div with classname live inside content.php or does it live inside the page that calls content.php?

Comment: The div classname lives in content.php and is appended into the page that calls it

Comment: Nooooooooo :) Use data attributes instead please. `<div class='classname' data-contentID='4'>...` `$('.classname').data('contentID')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to find the <script> and eval it. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

If you are using jQuery,then you can do:

```
$('#container script').each(function (i) {eval(this.innerHtml()} ));
```

Comment: I tried adding this in and its throwing me an syntax error - unexpected symbol "}"... I don't see where this has any syntax mistakes though?

Comment: Sorry try this, $('#container script').each(function (i) {eval(this.innerHtml());} );